# ASP.NET Core - AJAX array looks like is not populated and passed to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-core

I am having a problem passing an array using AJAX to the controller.

Below is SQL table structure screenshot:

[Here is SQL table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DtqO.png)

Here is the VIEW

```
$("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {

            var items = new Array();
            $("#tblItems TBODY TR").each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                var item = {};
                item.ItemID = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
                item.ProInvoiceNum = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
                item.InvoiceNum = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
                item.ProductNum = row.find("TD").eq(3).html();
                item.ItemDiscount = row.find("TD").eq(4).html();
                item.ItemAmount = row.find("TD").eq(5).html();
                items.push(item);
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Items/AddItems",
                data: JSON.stringify(items),
                traditional: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
                }
            });
        });
```

When I want to save the JSON array result the controller returns that 0 records are added to DB.

Is there any possibility that for instance "ItemId" should be parsed because it's of int type and it is string in array, right?

Here is the post Action in the CONTROLLER

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddItems([FromBody]IEnumerable<Items> items)
        {
                //Loop and insert records.
                foreach (Items item in items)
                {
                    _context.Items.Add(item);
                }

                int insertedRecords = _context.SaveChanges();
                return Json(insertedRecords);     
        }
```

I really appreciate any help on this, I tried to fix this in many ways, but now my brain is blocked with possible ideas to fix this.

If you need some more details please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that some of your properties are not string types and therefore they are not being set correctly when model binding.

I would name the class item rather than items because that is the convention used with Entity framework.   Looking at your table structure your item class should then be defined something like this

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ProInvoiceNum { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNum { get; set; }
    public string ProductNum { get; set; }
    public byte ItemDiscount { get; set; }
    public int ItemAmount { get; set; }
}
```

The problem you have is that the model binder is sent JSON which has strings and a model with some integers.  I think the simplest solution is to use the parsInt method on the client.  In other words change your item populating lines to this

```
item.ItemID = parseInt(row.find("TD").eq(0).html());
item.ProInvoiceNum = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
item.InvoiceNum = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
item.ProductNum = row.find("TD").eq(3).html();
item.ItemDiscount = parseInt(row.find("TD").eq(4).html());
item.ItemAmount = parseInt(row.find("TD").eq(5).html());
```

Then your JSON will contain numbers where it needs to rather than strings.